# SQL - Replacing Duplicate Value With Empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table that look like this

```
Company  Date       Paper  Condition
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Release Second Term
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Add Third Term
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Append First Term
```

Im trying to replace duplicate with empty which will result in

```
Company  Date       Paper  Condition
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Release Second Term
                           Add Third Term
                           Append First Term
```

So Far all i've tried is using `distinct` and it does not work as expected.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to permanently change the data in the table, or do this only during retrieval?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @horse its mysql and yes only during retrieval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Case When Rank=1 then
            `Company`
       Else ''
       End as Company,
       Case When Rank=1 then
            `Date`
       Else ''
       End as `Date`,
       Case When Rank=1 then
            `Paper`
       Else ''
       End as `Paper`, 
       `Condition` 
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @Company != t.Company OR @Date != t.`Date` OR  @Paper != t.`Paper`
                     THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @Company := t.Company AS var_category,
               @Date := t.`Date` AS var_Date,
               @Paper := t.`Paper` AS var_Paper 
          FROM Table1 t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := null, @Company := '') r ) x
```

Output

```
Company     Date        Paper   Condition
Company1    19-12-2007  PaperA  Release Second Term
                                Add Third Term
                                Append First Term
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42c636/5

Comment: Welcome!! @Karen

Comment: Check now updated answer which is more accurate and also check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42c636/5 link for better understanding

Comment: I was about to ask if same company has different paper but you covered it. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Welcome!! @Karen :-)