# Rebuilding MySQL to MSSQL (Microsoft Server SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510011/sql-replacing-duplicate-value-with-empty).
But the problem is, the query only work for MySQL not MSSQL. I tried to convert it by hand but I can't seem to understand the equivalent of some syntax like `:= [value] AS [value]`

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to convert that MySQL query to use it on MSSQL?

EDIT : Expected output

Input

```
Company  Date       Paper  Condition
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Release Second Term
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Add Third Term
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Append First Term
Company2 19-12-2007 PaperA Add Third Term
Company2 19-12-2007 PaperA Append First Term
Company2 19-12-2007 PaperA Add Third Term
```

Output

```
Company  Date       Paper  Condition
Company1 19-12-2007 PaperA Release Second Term
                           Add Third Term
                           Append First Term
Company2 19-12-2007 PaperA Add Third Term
                           Append First Term
                           Add Third Term
```

Comment: That solution is an ugly workaround for MySQL's lack of window functions. In SQL Server you can simply use `row_number()` instead

Comment: Please show us your MySQL query.  We may need more information than this as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen im actually reusing his MySQL query on this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42c636/5 , the only part i tweaked is the column and works perfectly fine. But again this is for mysql so it never works on MSSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is the equivalent for := [value] As [value] if i may know? , cause im trying to rewrite the code but i cant understand the equivalent.

Comment: You should still include your code.  Links can break over time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the on-work MSSQL one or the finished MySQL?

Comment: I think MySQL is irrelevant here. Just post the SQL query you've tried. Is the objective here to understand MySQL syntax or do you just want to solve your problem in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL 2017+, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT Company, Date, Paper, STRING_AGG(Condition,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) AS Condition
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Company, Date, Paper;
```

In earlier SQL versions, use FOR XML along with STUFF to remove the extra line break:

```
SELECT Company, Date, Paper
    ,STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+Condition FROM dbo.Example AS b
    WHERE b.Company = a.Company AND b.Date = a.Date AND b.Paper = a.Paper
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Condition
FROM dbo.YourTable AS a
GROUP BY Company, Date, Paper;
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks!